# Find Derivative of Fraction Using First Principles

Tags: calculus

I am really struggling with a highschool calculus question which involves finding the derivative of a function using the first principles.

The question is as follows:

Find the derivative of f(x) = (3x-1)/(x+2) when x ≠ -2

I am having trouble with this problem because I am unsure what to do when I have put my function of f(x+h) into the equation f'(x) = [f(x+h)-f(x)]/h.

This is a link so my working so far and I would greatly appreciate it if you could please explain the steps how to finish this question.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15qqnbn&s=8#.VOq8wPmUePt

Thank you,

Geoffrey

Comment: Your working looks fine. Just keep manipulating your limit (you should know how to simplify the addition or subtractions of two fractions) and use the limit laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some tedious algebra you have
${f(x+h)-f(x) \over h} = {7 \over x^2+(h+4)x + 2h +4}$, which is 'nicely' behaved at $h=0$, so we see that
$\lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x) \over h} = {7 \over x^2+4x + 4} = {7 \over (x+2)^2 }$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It is very clear and shows the steps.

Comment: Delighted to help!